# How to take video from gallery like image inside application in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios6, ios7

In my application i need to take video from simulator and i need to upload to server.can any one help to me.Please provide any solution as soon as possible.

Thanks & Regards
T.swathi

Comment: [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

Answer (score 1):

First, create a UIImagePickerController

On your class, you will need to implement the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol and wire it up to the delegate property on the picker. You should be able to get the location of the media selected from didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo once the user has selected something.

//Check in iOS Device not in Simulator

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // this is the file system url of the media
    NSURL* videoUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    // TODO: read in data at videoUrl and write upload it to your server
}
```

Comment: imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,nil];
This delegate method is not calling then the way i am creating UIImagepicker is following

Comment: you declare your delegate in .h file <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate >

Comment: <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> use this delegate

Comment: I used two delegates in images after clicking photo it vl call this method - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info like that after selecting video it is not calling the method that problem i am facing

Comment: @user3092286 if you declared delegate and assign. Then it must be called while you select any item from gallery. Debug your code and see what exactly the problem.

Comment: Ok now i will check in device

Comment: i checked in device it is not calling didfinish method

Comment: - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker;
this method is calling but this method is not calling after tap on video in gallery - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;

Answer (score 0):

Use this function may be help full

```
-(void)selectVideoButtonClicked:(id)sender{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType =    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,      nil];
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

and take delege of "UIImagePickerControllerDelegate" & and import framework and using delegate function pick video from library

MobileCoreServices.framework first import in project and after than import in file CoreServices/CoreServices.h

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    // Handle a movie capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
        == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:  UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
        NSLog(@" Video Path %@",moviePath);
        NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc]init];

        //If you wants get File Name Then you can use this
        if ([moviePath rangeOfString:@"//"].location != NSNotFound) {
            NSString *separatorString = @"//";
           NSArray *disSplit = [moviePath componentsSeparatedByString:separatorString];
            fileName = disSplit[1] ;
            // [self videoUploadingDirect:moviePath];
        }

        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
            }
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Thanks :)